# Code editor plugin for MS outlook 2003?

Tags: .net, editor, outlook, fckeditor

I constantly find myself sending .NET code snippets to other developers using MS outlook email. Is there a code editor plugin I can use that can help in formatting and copy/paste (something like SO editor?

Comment: Why the Outlook formating is not good enough for you? After all the Outlook text editor is way better then SO's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend setting message type to plain text. With that you should be able to copy and paste while still maintaining the formatting.